# Defining a functional over the set of all bounded functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $B_{\mathbb{R}} = \{f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},\ \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(x)| < \infty\}$ and $p\colon B_\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be $$p(f) = \inf_\sigma\limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}f(x + \sigma_{k})$$
where $\sigma = (\sigma_{1},\ldots,\sigma_{N})$ is running over all possible finite sets of positive real numbers.

I am trying to proof that:

1. $p$ is well defined
2. $p(cf) = cp(f) $ $\forall c > 0$
3. $p(f + g) \leq p(f) + p(g)$
4. $a \leq p(f) \leq $ if $a \leq f(x) \leq b$
5. $p(f(x) - f(x + a)) = p (f(x+a) - f(x)) = 0$

I believe (1) and (4) are direct results of the fact that $f \in B_{\mathbb{R}}$. Because if $f$ is limited, than that limsup is just the bound of the funcion and thus we'd have the inf of a constant (a set of only one element).

(2) for me is also a direct result of the properties of sup and inf.

Thus I am having trouble with the inequalities I get from trying to prove (3) and (5). I would love to get some hints with these.

This is from the paper "On uniformly bounded linear transformations in Hilbert space" by B. Sz.-Nagy.

For (3):

I know that for a fixed $\sigma$, if $f, g \in B_{\mathbb{R}}$ then: $$\limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}f(x + \sigma_{k}) + g(x + \sigma_{k}) = \limsup_{x\to\infty}[\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}f(x + \sigma_{k}) + \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}g(x + \sigma_{k})] \leq \limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}f(x + \sigma_{k}) + \limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}g(x + \sigma_{k})$$ 
But if I apply the inf I get:
$$\inf_\sigma[\limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}f(x + \sigma_{k}) + \limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^{N}g(x + \sigma_{k})] \leq p(f + g)$$

Can I apply de $inf$ for f then for g to get the inequality?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

(3) comes from $\limsup a_n + \limsup b_n\geq \limsup (a_n+b_n)$ which in turn comes from without the lim.

(5) consider $\sigma=(a,2a,3a,\dots,Na)$ and similar.

Comment: Thanks! I got to this point on (3), but then I get stuck when applying the inf. Because I'd have the wrong side of the inequality using that $inf(A) + inf(B) \leq inf(A + B)$.

Comment: For (5), if $\sigma = (a, 2a, 3a, \ldots, Na)$ I get $limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{N}f(x + a) - f(x + (N+1)a)$. How can I guarantee that this goes to 0? What if the function on $x+a$ is positive and in $x+(n+1)a$ it is negative and I get something that doen't goes to 0?